# CMake generated Solution, generated Sourcefiles not visible in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I got a CSharp project which uses a generated source file. The sourcefile is generated as a `PRE_BUILD` command.

```
add_custom_command(
      TARGET ServiceTest PRE_BUILD
      COMMAND cmd.exe /c "@echo content of file > \"$(ProjectDir)sourcefile.cs\""
   )
```

The file generated is included this way and located in the binary tree of that project:

```
set(SOURCE_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/sourcefile.cs")
set_source_files_properties(${SOURCE_FILE} PROPERTIES GENERATED true)
add_executable(ServiceTest <Some other Sources> ${SOURCE_FILE})
```

My problem is that I can't seem to visually get the generated file into the explorer in Visual Studio. I tried reloading the project and checking the projectfile itself. Everything looks ok. The only difference is that the root folder of the source is different. I also thought of cmake not finding the file so I also tried an empty initial file. It does not work.

Does anyone have an idea how I could get Visual Studio to immediately show the generated Source?

Comment: Do not use `add_custom_command(TARGET)` command flow. Instead use `add_custom_command(OUTPUT)` flow where you could specify (in OUTPUT option) which file your command generates.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this version too. The generated file still isn't visible in Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: Might be something to do with the GENERATED property, the docs say it might be not visible in some IDEs.

Comment: That could be the reason but when looking into the project file the file is actually there. So I thought that realoading the project in the IDE would fix this. But even that makes no difference.

Comment: With a command like `COMMAND cmd.exe /c "@echo content of file > \"$(ProjectDir)sourcefile.cs\""` you're restricting yourself to a single generator on a single operating system. It's best to avoid this. You could easily create a cmake script for doing this for you making the logic build system and platform independent. Since all of the file contents seem to be hardcoded in the cmake file though, why not just use `file(WRITE)` during the configuration?

Comment: Btw: note that with the approach you presented cmake only knows that the file is generated; it doesn't know how it's generated which is a problem...